# How to replace asterisk with second column value

Tags: mysql

1) Can we use if condition with in select statement in sql
2) in stored procedure i need the below condition to be satisfied
a)I have two columns from different tables that needs to be merged and if special character is present in column 1 , asterisk should be replaced with second column value
b) if no asterisk then normal merging the column

```
Column 1
---------
UAT 
ST*
UAT*S
UT

Column 2
---------
12
10
9
6
```

I want result as

```
UAT12
ST10
UAT9s
UT6
```

Comment: show up, whet ever you tried.

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

1) Using `IF`:

```
SELECT 
IF(column1 LIKE '%*%', REPLACE(column1, '*', column2), CONCAT(column1, column2))
FROM tableName
```

2) Using `CASE` :

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN column1 LIKE '%*%' 
    THEN REPLACE(column1, '*', column2)
    ELSE CONCAT(column1, column2)
END 
FROM tableName
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sir, just want to know what if the two columns from different tables, so we cant use from tablename.. but how to modify column as **.Column

Comment: JOINs won't help, if there's no relationship

Comment: And iif is not a MySQL construction